# Draw Rectangle around border less form

Tags: vb6

I am trying to draw rectangle around border less form by simply drawing lines around forms, but the problem is Form bottom and Form left lines are not drawn Here is a code use for drawing on Form_Paint

```
 Line (0, 0)-(ScaleWidth, 0), vbWhite  ' work
 Line (0, 0)-(0, ScaleHeight), vbWhite ' work
 Line (ScaleWidth, 0)-(ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight), vbWhite ' not working
 Line (0, ScaleHeight)-(ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight), vbWhite ' not working
```

form is re-sizable so drawing rectangle create a problem when i re-size form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you need to draw the line yourself? you could use a shape control en resize it in **Form_Resize**.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Call shp.Move(0, 0, Me.ScaleWidth, Me.ScaleHeight)
End Sub
```

The reason **Line** draws one pixel to far has propably got to do with the fact it is 0 based, and in reality you want it to put the pixel at position **ScaleWidth**, which is 1 pixel beyond the screen, as **ScaleWidth** is '1 based'..
So if you do want to draw the line yourself you could use the following (if your scalemode is set to twips (the default)):

```
Line (0, 0)-(ScaleWidth - Screen.TwipsPerPixelX, ScaleHeight - Screen.TwipsPerPixelY), vbWhite, B
```

Comment: shape solution work fine for me thanks for your help